# Text processing - join every two lines with commas

Tags: text-processing, paste

I have more than 1000 lines in a file. The file starts as follows (line numbers added):

```
Station Name
Station Code
A N DEV NAGAR
ACND
ABHAIPUR
AHA
ABOHAR
ABS
ABU ROAD
ABR
```

I need to convert this to a file, with comma separated entries by joining every two lines. The final data should look like

```
Station Name,Station Code
A N DEV NAGAR,ACND
ABHAIPUR,AHA
ABOHAR,ABS
ABU ROAD,ABR
...
```

What I was trying was - trying to write a shell script and then `echo` them with comma in between. But I guess a simpler effective one-liner would do the job here may be in `sed`/`awk`.

Any ideas?

Comment: @l0b0 You edited out the OP's remark that the line numbers are "only there for explanation"...

Comment: @jasonwryan Sorry, I thought the *lines* were there for explanation. Parse error at line 0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605232/merge-two-lines-into-one

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Simply use `cat` (if you like cats ;-)) and `paste`:

```
cat file.in | paste -d, - - > file.out
```

Explanation: `paste` reads from a number of files and pastes together the corresponding lines (line 1 from first file with line 1 from second file etc):

```
paste file1 file2 ...
```

Instead of a file name, we can use `-` (dash). `paste` takes first line from file1 (which is stdin). Then, it wants to read the first line from file2 (which is also stdin). However, since the first line of stdin was already read and processed, what now waits on the input stream is the *second* line of stdin, which `paste` happily glues to the first one. The `-d` option sets the delimiter to be a comma rather than a tab.

Alternatively, do

```
cat file.in | sed "N;s/\n/,/" > file.out
```

P.S. Yes, one can simplify the above to

```
< file.in sed "N;s/\n/,/" > file.out
```

or

```
< file.in paste -d, - - > file.out
```

which has the advantage of not using `cat`.

However, I did not use this idiom *on purpose*, for clarity reasons -- it is less verbose and I like `cat` (CATS ARE NICE). So please do not edit.

Alternatively, if you prefer paste to cats (paste is the command to concatenate files horizontally, while cat concatenates them vertically), you may use:

```
paste file.in | paste -d, - -
```

Comment: Just to mention it again. Line numbers are not a part of file :)

Comment: The `paste`  command perfectly works, can you please give a little more explanation about it. The hyphens ???

Comment: The hyphens mean "read from stdin". If the same input source is repeated, paste knows to read from it several times per row of output.

Comment: @sch: cool edit, I won't touch it :-)

Comment: With respect to your `cat` argument. Does `sed "N;s/\n/,/" file.in > file.out` not work?

Comment: Of course it does. As I wrote, I use that particular form for clarity.

Comment: This type of construction is why I absolutely love the UNIX, "do one thing and do it well" mentality. This just about defines elegance and simplicity.

Answer (score 15):

In case anyone landing here is looking to combine all lines into a CSV one liner, try

```
cat file | tr '\n' ','
```

Answer (score 5):

```
sed 'N;s/\n/,/' file
```

Using sed, join(N) every 2 lines, and replace the newline(\n) with ",".

Comment: This is **exactly** what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

For the complete set of answers, a possible `awk` solution may be:

```
awk 'NR%2==1 {printf $0","} NR%2==0 { print $0}' *file*
```

Comment: @downvoter: What is wrong with my answer to deserve a downvote? How can it be improved?

Comment: Maybe because the lazy `printf`? Will fail in the rare case when a station name contains a format specifier. (See http://pastebin.com/wgxFttrJ for an example.) But this is just a guess, the downvote is not from me.

Answer (score 3):

```
paste -sd ',\n' file.in > file.out
```

Also note that because we're merely replacing one character with another (every other newline with a comma), we can work on the input file in place:

```
paste -sd ',\n' file.in 1<> file.in
```

(but beware it might not work on non-Unix systems that have CRLF terminators (like Microsoft ones) that some emulated POSIX `paste` might treat in a non-Unix way)

Comment: What does that `1` is doing here in `1<>`? is that a typo?

Comment: @αғsнιη, see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87461/21233)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-liner (though potentially millions-of-commands-run-er) using pure Bash:

```
(IFS=; while read -r name; do read -r code; printf '%s\n" "$name,$code"; done < file.in) > file.out
```

I use a subshell (the paranthesis) so that I won't have to store and restore `IFS`. Which one otherwise should do as to not mess up the users environment in case the source is sourced. The alternative would be to pass that new IFS only to `read` as in `IFS= read -r name`, `IFS= read -r code`.

The fact that all the commands in the loop are built in the shell makes its performance acceptable and is even faster than the other solutions for small files. But many people would consider it bad practice and one should be careful when generalising it to anything else.

Comment: in general yay for using subshells to localize environment changes. But in this case it's not needed: you can instead do `while IFS='\n' read -r name; do IFS='\n' read -r code ... done < file.in`, which is an idiom I often see in shell scripts. The `-r` flag to `read` means "interpret the character '\' followed by the character 'n' in the stdin stream as two characters, rather than as a newline." Arguably, it may be more aesthetic to create the subshell as you do than to repeat the `IFS='\n'`.

Comment: @dubiousjim: The `-r` improved the solution technically. Great! I'm not a fan of the idea of passing a changed `IFS` twice. If I had used one read, super nice, but not twice. Of course that's a matter of *opinion*. Using a subshell is a bit over the general Bash knowledge I would say, so a lot of folks will have trouble understanding its purpose. That's a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

Hoary old chestnut of an `awk`idiom

```
awk '{ORS=NR%2?",":"\n";print}' file
Station Name,Station Code
A N DEV NAGAR,ACND
ABHAIPUR,AHA
ABOHAR,ABS
ABU ROAD,ABR
```

Comment: `awk '{ORS=NR%2?",":"\n"};1'` is shorter and more idiom

Comment: @cuonglm, i doubt it. In this instance it's still a one-liner despite the `print` and the intent is clear. `1` is just as clear to old `awk` hands such as myself but I prefer `print`

Comment: This was the first simple solution that I found that was easily configurable to more than 2 lines.  I fought with `sed` for a while before searching, but `awk` made combining every 4 lines easier.  Saved me a trip to the `$EDITOR`!

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
seq 0 70 | xargs -L 2 | sed 's/ /,/g'
```

Output: ( note:  `xargs -L number_of_columns` works nicely with most any number of columns not just every two lines)

```
0,1
2,3
4,5
6,7
8,9
10,11
12,13
14,15
16,17
18,19
20,21
22,23
24,25
26,27
28,29
30,31
32,33
34,35
36,37
38,39
40,41
42,43
44,45
46,47
48,49
50,51
52,53
54,55
56,57
58,59
60,61
62,63
64,65
66,67
68,69
70
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible with perl too,

`perl -pe 's/^\d+\.\s+//;$.&1?chomp:print","' file`

Answer (score 0):

POSIX solution with `pr`:

```
pr -2 -a -t -s, file
```

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pr.html